# obtener carpeta de una ruta

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista con direcciones de carpeta, que despues recorro con un `foreach`. Las ruta se ven asi

```
C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\10-21-2020
C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\10-20-2020
```

En un momento determinado obtengo la fecha actual, al recorrer el `foreach` el nombre que se encuentra
al final de la ruta por ejemplo `"10-21-2020"` corresponde al 10 de octubre de 2020,
el cual debe ser igual a la fecha actual.

```
if (Path.GetDirectoryName(item) == fecha_actual)
    {
        
    }
```

He intendo sacar este nombre, pero sigo sin conseguirlo, mq sigeu enviando toda la ruta
y solo necesito `"10-21-2020"`

Comment: Prueba a realizar un `split('\')` y acceder al elemento 6. De esa forma puedes tener el nombre de la carpeta

Comment: Si el GetDirectoryName(item) esta obteniendo la fecha del modo correcto, fecha_actual lo corroborará. Prueba a mostrar que esta trayendo el metodo, y de que modo estas comparandolo tu en fecha_actual.

Comment: ehhh.. vos queres el nombre del directorio, o el nombre del archivo? el nombre del archivo es GetFileName

Comment: Solo el nombre del directorio

Comment: El método `GetDirectoryName()` devuelve un `String`, podrías usar algún método como `Substring()` para capturar lo que necesitas y comparar con la cadena de fecha que tienes. Lo digo como una posibilidad. Saludos

Comment: usa GetFileName.. probalo en tu ruta y vas a ver que devuelve el nombre de la ultima carpeta ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede hacer algo como esto, hacer un split y luego obtener la última posición y de esta forma le funciona con cualquier ruta:

```
string ruta = @"C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\10-21-2020";

            var division = ruta.Split("\\");

            var fecha = division[division.Length-1];

            Console.WriteLine(fecha);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Path.GetDirectoryName` devuelve una ruta completa cuando se le pasa una..

cuando vos le pasas esta cadena:

```
C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\10-21-2020
```

lo que esa funcion hace es buscar hasta el ultimo \ y devuelve todo hasta ahi

```
C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX
```

si `10-21-2020` es tambien una carpeta, esa funcion no lo sabe y piensa que es un archivo...

pero, aprovechando eso, si eso es una carpeta, podes usar la funcion `GetFileName`, que te va a devolver exactamente eso...